# Java TextFile Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, text-files

I basically want to print all that comes above when i encounter a line 
So what i am doing is I am creating a new Thread  whenever i encounter a new line. I want to know how to do this. This code below which i wrote is giving wrong outputs i am not able to understand. pls do help

This is the Java code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class ThreadDemo extends Thread {
private Thread t;
private String threadName[];

ThreadDemo(String[] name, int le) {
    threadName = name;
    System.out.println("Creating " + le);
}

public void run() {
    // System.out.println("Running " + threadName);
    try {
        // System.out.println("come");
        for (int i = 0; threadName[i] != null; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + "y " + threadName[i]);
            // Let the thread sleep for a while.
            Thread.sleep(0);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Thread " + threadName + " interrupted.");
    }
    System.out.println("Thread " + threadName + " exiting.");
}

public void start() {
    System.out.println("Starting " + threadName);
    if (t == null) {
        System.out.println("come");
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }
}

}

public class TestThread {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("/e:/Amazonsupernew.txt");
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter("/e:/multicode1.txt");
    BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
    Map<String, ArrayList<String>> CusId = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
    String line;
    String[] send = new String[10000];
    int i = 0;
    while ((line = file.readLine()) != null) {
        send[i++] = line;
        if (line.isEmpty()) {
            send[i - 1] = null;
            String temp[] = send;
            ThreadDemo T = new ThreadDemo(temp, i);
            T.start();
            i = 0;
        }
    }
}
}
```

File
[This is the text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5Ayl.png)

i just want to print each Ids information each one for each thread

Comment: Why do you need start method in your thread? Do you know that you will end up creating new thread for every line whereas  for this excercise purpose you could have used threadpool.

Comment: What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? Why don't you use `le` in ThreadDemo?

Comment: i expect to print all the lines between two consecutive empty lines. but it is printing something random just random lines

Comment: Your realize that threads run concurrently, right? And that thre lines printed by all threads will thus be interlaced.